# javascript, XMLHttpRequest led memory leak

Tags: javascript, memory, xmlhttprequest

I am try to load files using `XMLHttpRequest`,but it always occupy memory and never release.Code:

```
    load = (taskInfo) => {
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    taskInfo.forEach(taskItem => {
      request.open('GET', taskItem.frame.path, false);
      request.send(null);
    })
}
```

Everytime I call `load()`,memory usage will increase and never release,it will increase `100MB(total file size)` one time.I don`t know why.

Is somebody help me?

Comment: Is that all of the code? Are you actually doing something with the request?

Comment: Define "never." Have you pushed the limits of memory? Remember that JavaScript engines do garbage collection according to their own arcane rules. There certainly doesn't seem to be a problem with that code (other than not doing anything with the result of the GET).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I never do something with the request.And it will run out of memory and get "AW,snap" on chrome when I always call load().I had use FileLoader in THREEJS some where,and I realize that when I comment FileLoader`s code,load() will run normaly and no occupy memory.